# Convert HTML Input Form to Windows Form that uses Web Service

Tags: html, winforms, web-services

I have a legacy HTML basic form that has 2 input fields that upon clicking on the Submit button, it hits a service and returns what looks like viable XML data for me to consume.

Here is the source of the HTML file (got it via View Source):

```
<html>
<body>
  <form name="input" action="http://CompanyX/WebServices" method="post">
    EmployeeId: <input type="text" name="EmpId" />
    Department: <input type="text" name="DeptId" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

My task is to create something similar but using Windows Forms.  I am uncertain as to what class I should use to communicate to that service.  By the way, I don't know what technology that service is based on.  Should I use HttpWebRequest, WebRequest, WebClient, etc.?  Also, upon this POST, how do I submit those 2 fields in my request.  I should not have a problem reading that rendered XML data.  I just need some tips on what to use for accessing a web services via a WinForms application.

Comment: [Your first C# Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863/Your-first-C-Web-Service)

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  See, the "WebServices" are already created.  I just want know how I consume/execute them via Win Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

In the Solution Explorer, right click ***References*** and select ***Add Web Reference...***.

In the dialog to pops up, set the path to the WSDL of your webservice and click ***Add Reference***.

You will then have a new ***Web References*** entry in the project's tree.
Double click the added reference to see it in the Object Browser, and start having fun.

[image]